# Instance method aliases to builtin-functions in Python

Tags: python, oop, methods, metaclass, python-3.9

Trying to code as efficient as possible object-oriented implementation of priority queue in Python, I faced an interesting behavior. The following code works fine

```py
from heapq import heappush


class PriorityQueue(list):
    __slots__ = ()

    def push(self, item):
        heappush(self, item)
```

However, I really didn’t want to write a wrapper method for calling `heappush`, as it incurs additional overhead for calling the function. I reasoned that since the `heappush` signature uses `list` as the first argument, while aliasing the `push` class attribute with the `heappush` function, the latter becomes a full-fledged class instance method. However, my assumption turned out to be false, and the following code gives an error.

```py
from heapq import heappush


class PriorityQueue(list):
    __slots__ = ()
    push = heappush


PriorityQueue().push(0)
# TypeError: heappush expected 2 arguments, got 1
```

But going to `cpython` [heapq](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/heapq.py) source code, just copying `heappush` implementation into the scope and applying the same logic works fine.

```py
from heapq import _siftdown


def heappush(heap, item):
    """Push item onto heap, maintaining the heap invariant."""
    heap.append(item)
    _siftdown(heap, 0, len(heap) - 1)


class PriorityQueue(list):
    __slots__ = ()
    push = heappush


pq = PriorityQueue()
pq.push(0)
pq.push(-1)
pq.push(3)
print(pq)
# [-1, 0, 3]
```

- The first question: Why does it happen? How does `Python` decide which function is appropriate for binding as an instance method and which is not?
- The second question: What is the difference between `heappush` in the `cpython/Lib/heapq.py` and the actual `heappush` from the `heapq` module? They are actually different since the following code gives an error

```py
from dis import dis
from heapq import heappush


dis(heappush)
# TypeError: don't know how to disassemble builtin_function_or_method objects
```

- The third question: How can one force `Python` to bind native `heappush` as an instance method? Some metaclass magic?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What takes place is that Python offers pure Python implementations of a lot of its algorithms in the standard library **even when it contains acceletated native code implementations** of the same algorithms.

The heapq library is one of those - if you pick the file you link to, but close to the end, you will see the code snippet which looks if the native version is available, and overwrites the Python version, which has the code you copy and pasted - https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/76cd81d60310d65d01f9d7b48a8985d8ab89c8b4/Lib/heapq.py#L580

```
try:
    from _heapq import *
except ImportError:
    pass
...
```

The native version of `heappush` is loaded into the module, and there is no easy way of getting a reference to the original Python function, short of getting to the actual file source code.

Now, the point: why do native functions do not work as class methods?
heappush's type is `builtin_function_or_method`, in constrast with `function` for pure Python functions - and one of the major diference is that the second object type features a `__get__` method. This `__get__` makes Python defined functions work as "descriptors": the `__get__` method is called when one retrieves the attribute from an instance. For ordinary functions, this call records the `self` parameter and injects it when the actual function is called.

Thus, it is easy to write an "instancemethod" decorator that will make built-in functions work as Python functions and usable as methods. However, the overhead of creating a partial or a lambda function should surpass the overhead of the extra function call you are trying to eliminate - so you should get no speed gains from it, although it might still read as more elegant:

```
class instancemethod:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return lambda *args, **kwargs: self.func(instance, *args, **kwargs)

import heapq

class MyHeap(list):
    push = instancemethod(heapq.heappush)
```

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer.

Yes, the code you suggested does throw an error. But why then the native Python `heappush` from my first code snippet works fine?

Logically, there should also be a check for correspondence between `self` and the `list` type.

Comment: Sorry for that, the first argument for the self.func call has to be `instance` - I had written `self` - and that is because it was failing the `isinstance(x, list)` internal check. The solution actually works (although, as explained, it should be even slower than a simple wrap)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it the way python calls a function. When you try `print(type(heappush))` you will notice the difference.

For question 1, the decorator that use to identify which function is which type (i.e. `staticmethod`, `classmethod`) is like call and process the function and return the processed one to that name. So the data that determine that should be in some attribute of the function. After I find where it is, question 3 may be solved.

For question 2. When you import the built-in function, it will be in the type of `builtin_function_or_method`. But if you copy and paste it, it was defined in your code so it's just `function`. That may cause the interpreter to call it a static method instead of an instance method.

Comment: you got the right clues, but did not get quite to the point - the change in function type is not, of course, due to it being "copy and pasted" to a different module

Comment: You got the reason for that (in your answer). But to clarify, it's like you implement a function in the interpreter as a copy from some "python" code. While you import a "native" code. But it's fair to say that in the general case. Thanks for the clarification and your explaination.